# Servlet call is returning the wrong json string because wrong constructor is used through ResponseEntity Object

Tags: spring, constructor

My config :
Spring 4
Jackson 2.9
Angular 8

I have a pojo with two constructors :

```
public Notification(int code, String message, List<T> objets) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
    this.objets = objets;
}   

public Notification(int code, String message, T objet) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
    this.objet = objet;
}
```

The purpose of this pojo is adding an internal code and a string message to the result of a request, the request can either result in a object or in a list of objects (or no object at all but i did not wanted to write every constructor above).

My problem is that when my query result is a list, and i think i am using the constructor with the list of objects . However the query response in my browser terminal is a null object. So I suppose the second constructor is used.

why is it not using my first constructor?

Here is my repository :

```
public Notification<Prelevement> findActiveTransferts(int id){
    LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    Date date =   java.sql.Date.valueOf(currentTime.toLocalDate());
    String sql = "from Prelevement pre where :date between pre.dateDebut and pre.dateFin and pre.compte =:idCompte";

    try {
        Compte acc = (Compte)this.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Compte acc where acc.id =:id").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
        List<Prelevement> list = (List<Prelevement>) this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql).setParameter("date", date).setParameter("idCompte", acc).getResultList();
        return new Notification<Prelevement>(Notification.OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL, "Nous avons trouvé "+list.size()+" éléments correspondants à votre recherche", list);
    }catch(NoResultException nre) {
        return new Notification<Prelevement>(Notification.DB_NO_DATA_FOUND, "Nous avons trouvé aucun élément correspondant à votre recherche");
    }       
}
```

and my RestController :

```
@PostMapping("/pre/get")
public ResponseEntity<Notification<Prelevement>> get(@RequestBody DTOAcc dto){

    Notification<Prelevement> result = ((PrelevementRepository)repository).findActiveTransferts(dto.getId());
    System.out.println(result);
    return new ResponseEntity<Notification<Prelevement>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I expect the json string in my browser terminal to be a list of objects and not an object when a list is expected.

Result json string is :
    {"code":0,"message":"Nous avons trouvé 1 éléments correspondants à votre recherche","objet":null}

and should be : 
    {"code":0,"message":"Nous avons trouvé 1 éléments correspondants à votre recherche","objets":[
{"id":"0", ... other attributes}
]}

the toString method of the object sent by Spring to the browser is as follow
Notification [code=0, message=Nous avons trouvé 1 éléments correspondants à votre recherche, objets=[pro.logikal.comptes.entity.Prelevement@16b51ef6]] so we can see that my request has found a list of object (a list of one object to be accurate).

Can you please show me the way?

Comment: First you suggest that you get null, then you suggest you get a json. Wht do you **actually** get? Post the JSON. Post the Angular code used to get this JSON and print it.

Comment: Updated my post with the output json strings in my browser terminal

Answer (score 0):

Found out my mistake, I did not generate any getter nor setter for this list. The constructor resulted invisible so it got to the next constructor.